# Simple Java Math

Tags: java, math

So I know that this is super simple, and I'm sorry for having to ask this on here. Unfortuntely, I am confused and have no one else to ask...

Anyway, I'm trying to use Java to solve the following equation:

```
 __________________
√ (3.1^17 + 2.7^11)
```

The code that I have right now doesn't work. It is:

```
public class Math
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double a = 3.1
        double b = 2.7;

        double c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,17) + Math.pow(b,11));

        System.out.println(c); 
   }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - is not a real question.

Comment: What does not work about this code? Stack traces?

Comment: Consider using an IDE, such as Eclipse, to ease your semantic troubles.

Comment: I so don't agree with the trigger-happy closing of questions like this. It's blatantly obvious at a quick glance what is wrong with this code. Given that, there's an opportunity to help someone.

Comment: I apologize for my apparently completely idiotic question. To those of you who tried to help me I genuinely appreciate it; to those of you that I have seemed to piss off by posting this stupid question I apologize. Next time I need help I will certainly go elsewhere.

Comment: @user2499376: Please stay. The Stack Overflow community is better than this. We're generally a pretty helpful bunch although it doesn't always show. Either way, I'm very glad that we could help. Good luck.

Comment: In the future you should *at least* include the error message you get, or if there isn't any, a description of what the code does when you run it and what it should do. That way people don't have to guess. The same applies wherever you ask programming questions, not only Stack Overflow.

Comment: Understandable. Thank you for clarifying what I did wrong. I was trying not to bore everyone with the details because I figured that the mistake I made would be blatantly obvious to someone who is good with this stuff, but I completely understand why I should include a more in depth explanation of my question and the error I am attempting to resolve.

Answer (score 7):

Your class name is Math, you are trying to call `Math.function`, which does not exist in your class, you need to `refactor` your class name and import the class library.

Right click the file name, `Refactor > Rename`

If your class `must` be named math, you must call:

```
java.lang.Math.pow();
```

Another problem is that you are missing a `;` after:

```
double a = 3.1
```

Fix both of these problems and you will have a working code!

In the future, please post stack traces and specific problems are having.

Comment: No, this is not the main issue.

Comment: I found the main issue and added it to the answer. I saw this first error first as for me it would not even compile. I then noticed their class name was `Math` and that the real math lib was not imported.

Comment: It still won't compile even if you fix the semicolon, so your suggestion that you found the issue after fixing the semicolon is dubious.

Comment: I did not copy the entire code, as I already had a project setup in eclipse, I just copied the body of `main`

Answer (score 3):

Don't name your class `Math`, you need to give it a different name from the Java framework class [`Math`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html). Also, you need to fix `double a = 3.1` to have a semicolon at the end and add `import java.lang.Math`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class maths
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double a = 3.1;
    double b = 2.7;

    double c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,17) + Math.pow(b,11));

    System.out.println(c); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Comment: classname couldn't be a methodname. java.lang.Math should be imported.Also the semicolon.